# xCode 8, swift 3, Facebook SDK login using LoginManager have to click twice to open FB login form

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, facebook-login

I'm using below function to login with Facebook, but I always have to click Login button twice to open the Facebook login page.

I already tested on simulator and device. The first time I click login button, the app goes to loginManager.logIn (...) function, but it never get into completion handler until 2nd click.

Anyone has this issue and solution for it? I'm using xCode 8 and Swift 3

```
private func loginWithFB(){
    let loginManager = LoginManager()
    loginManager.logIn([ .publicProfile, .userFriends, .email ], viewController: self) { loginResult in
        switch loginResult {
        case .failed(let error):
            print(error)
        case .cancelled:
            print("User cancelled login.")
        case .success(let grantedPermissions, let declinedPermissions, let accessToken):

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where you called this loginWithFB

Comment: I added a Button and link it to this function. Not sure if I answered your question?

Answer (score 2):

This code works for me. The completion handler is called during each tap of the button.

Xcode version - 8.0

FBSDK version - 4.15.1

```
@IBAction func loginTest(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let loginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
        loginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions:["public_profile","user_friends","email"], from: self) {
            loginResult,error in
            print("completion handler called")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you use swift 3?

Comment: Yes I am using swift 3

Comment: Fb SDK version 4.15.1

Answer (score 2):

Have you put this in your appDelegate?

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool
{

    return SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(app, open: url, options: options)

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I face the same issue, I just initialize the Facebooklogin in didFinishLaunching.

Here is the code working for me:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:    [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
   FBSDKLoginManager.initialize()  // Initialize facebook login
   return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just use :

```
let fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
        fbLoginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["email"], from: self) { (result, error) in
            if (error == nil){
                let fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result!
                if fbloginresult.grantedPermissions != nil {
                    if(fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.contains("email"))
                    {
                        self.getFBUserData()
                        fbLoginManager.logOut()
                    }
                }
            }
        }

func getFBUserData(){
        if((FBSDKAccessToken.current()) != nil){
            FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email"]).start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
                if (error == nil){
                    self.dict = result as! [String : AnyObject]
                    print(result!)
                    print(self.dict)
                }
            })
        }
    }
```